# Import Google Sheet Data all at once to an existing sheet with data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Currently I have been using this script which imports data from a spreadsheet located in my google drive. The function works but imports the data one line at a time. Some times these sheets are 400+ rows and that takes a long time. I am looking for it to grab all data and import it into an existing spreadsheet and the end of the last value.

```
function getData() {

get_files = ['July1-2022'];
  
  var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = ssa.getSheetByName('CancelRawData');  
  
  for(z = 0; z < get_files.length; z++)
  {
  
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(get_files[z]);
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      break;
    }
  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    for(var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++)
    {  
      var nameSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i].getName()); 
      var nameRange = nameSheet.getDataRange();
      var nameValues = nameRange.getValues();
      
      for(var y = 1; y < nameValues.length; y++)
      {
        copySheet.appendRow(nameValues[y]); 
      }
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations, your data has been all imported", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- `appendRow` is used in a loop. The process cost will be high.
- In your script, `sheets` can be written by `var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets();`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script 1:

This script uses the Spreadsheet service (SpreadsheetApp).

```js
function getData() {
  // Retrieve values.
  get_files = ['July1-2022'];
  var values = [];
  for (z = 0; z < get_files.length; z++) {
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(get_files[z]);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      break;
    }
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets();
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
      values = [...values, ...sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues()];
    }
  }
  if (values.length == 0) return;

  // Put values.
  const maxLen = Math.max(...values.map(r => r.length));
  values = values.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('CancelRawData');
  copySheet.getRange(copySheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations, your data has been all imported", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

#### Modified script 2:

This script uses Sheets API. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function getData() {
  // Retrieve values.
  get_files = ['July1-2022'];
  var values = [];
  for (z = 0; z < get_files.length; z++) {
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(get_files[z]);
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      break;
    }
    var spreadsheetId = file.getId();
    var ranges = SpreadsheetApp.open(file).getSheets().map(s => `'${s.getSheetName()}'!${s.getDataRange().getA1Notation()}`);
    values = [...values, ...Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(spreadsheetId, { ranges }).valueRanges.flatMap(({ values }) => values)];
  }
  if (values.length == 0) return;

  // Put values.
  var dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.append({ values }, dstSS.getId(), 'CancelRawData', { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(" Congratulations, your data has been all imported", SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
}
```

#### Note:

- When these scripts are run, all files of `get_files` are retrieved and all values are retrieved from all sheets in all Spreadsheets, and the retrieved values are put to the destination sheet of `CancelRawData`.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.append](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append)

Comment: This works fantastic, is there a way to have it start on row two because I don't want the header in every data pull

Comment: @mrcodedini Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `is there a way to have it start on row two because I don't want the header in every data pull`, which script do you want to use in my proposed 2 scripts?

Comment: Modified script 1: Works perfect, that is the one I am using!

Comment: @mrcodedini Thank you for replying. From `Modified script 1: Works perfect, that is the one I am using!`, in this case, please modify `values = [...values, ...sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues()];` to `var [, ...temp] = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues(); values = [...values, ...temp];`. By this, the 1st row is not included from all sheets.